# Cannot see Submit button on manual workflow

Tags: workflow

I have a basic workflow, done with SPD 2010. It is a manual workflow all it does is copy an item from one calendar to another. When I try to initialize the workflow I get taken to the Start workflow page however no buttons exist on the page to start the workflow. I am not using a system account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the designer had put in some CSS that hid this section. Upon some corrective action with that the button came back.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how you configured the workflow before publishing:
 1. Is it attached to a list or a content type?
 2. Is it set to start Automatically on item creation or Manually?

Make sure you validate that on the workflow starting page before publishing it again. Also, after publishing, do remove older instances.

Comment: It is attached to a list. It is set to start manually. I have removed older instances. This is really bizarre, cant say I have ever seen this before. I am not getting anything in ULS logs or otherwise. I also tried deleting and recreating the workflow and had the same issue.